# Merging 2 images in Cocoa on Retina Macs

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

I'm trying to merge two images to a background image. This works fine on non-Retina Macs.

The resulting image has the size of my original background image. But on a MacBook Pro Retina the resulting image is doubled. I read that one should use `imageWithSize` for solving that issue cause since 10.8 / Retina support images aren't measured in pixels anymore; as we know it's points.

I've no clue how I should change my code to solve this.

What i have so far:

```
    NSSize size =  background.size  ;
    GLsizei width = (GLsizei)size.width;
    GLsizei height = (GLsizei)size.height;
    NSBitmapImageRep* imgRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL pixelsWide:width pixelsHigh:height bitsPerSample:8 samplesPerPixel:3 hasAlpha:NO isPlanar:NO colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace bytesPerRow:width*3 bitsPerPixel:0];  

#ifdef __MAC_10_8

    NSImage* backgroundWrapper = [NSImage imageWithSize:size flipped:YES drawingHandler:^(NSRect dstRect){ return [imgRep drawInRect:dstRect]; }];
    NSPoint backgroundPoint;
    backgroundPoint.x = 0;
    backgroundPoint.y = 0;
    [backgroundWrapper lockFocusFlipped:YES];
    [background drawAtPoint:backgroundPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    [firstImage firstImage fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    [backgroundWrapper unlockFocus];

    NSBitmapImageRep *bmpImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithData:[backgroundWrapper TIFFRepresentation]];
    [backgroundWrapper addRepresentation:bmpImageRep];
#else
    [background lockFocusFlipped:YES];
    [firstImage drawAtPoint:firstImagePoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    [background unlockFocus];
    NSBitmapImageRep *bmpImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]initWithData:[background TIFFRepresentation]];
    [background addRepresentation:bmpImageRep];
#endif

    NSData *data = [bmpImageRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties: nil];
```

How can I get this to work on a Retina display?

**edit**

I also tried this:

```
- (NSImage )drawImage:(NSImage)background with:(NSImage*)firstImage { 

    return [NSImage imageWithSize:NSMakeSize(3200, 2000) flipped:NO drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) { 
        NSPoint backgroundPoint; backgroundPoint.x = 0; 
        backgroundPoint.y = 0; 
        [background drawAtPoint:backgroundPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0]; 
        [firstImage drawAtPoint:backgroundPoint fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0]; 
        return true; 
    }];
}
```

But the resulting image is 6400x4000px

Comment: NSImages' size has never been in pixels; it has always been points.

Comment: What do you mean by “the resulting image is doubled”? What are the input and output sizes in both points (of the image) and pixels (of its representation(s))?

Comment: @noa background is NSImage* background = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundURL];

Comment: @PeterHosey if size is f.e. 1000x1000px the resulting image size on retina displays is 2000x2000px

Comment: @mightym: `size` is in points, not pixels. So, what's the size in points, and what are the representations' sizes in pixels?